# How can I create a value with a specific TypeRep

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types, casting

Using `Data.Typeable`, I can reify the type of a value -

```
typeOf :: Typeable a => a -> TypeRep
```

However, given a `TypeRep`, there seems to be no way to "set" a value to that type.

For example -

```
maybeIntType :: TypeRep
maybeIntType = typeOf (Just 100 :: Maybe Int)
```

But how do I use `maybeIntType` to create a `(Nothing :: Maybe Int)`?

Comment: You need a language with dependent types (literally "types that can depend on values") for that. Three popular dependently typed languages are Idris, Agda, and Coq (in order of "most focused on programming" to "most focused on theorem proving"); though I don't know to what extent those languages have analogs of `Typeable`.

Comment: If you are asking for this as a stepping-stone to some other goal, you should talk about that other goal; it may be possible to achieve without dependent types (e.g. maybe [`fromDyn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html#v:fromDyn) is enough for you).

Comment: I suppose you mean something like, _how do I use `maybeIntType` to create a `(mempty :: Maybe Int)`_?

Comment: As of GHC 7.10.2, the safe API of `Data.Typeable` makes `TypeRep`s almost useless except for printing, because all the cast operations require `Typeable` constraints, not just `TypeRep`s, and there's no safe way to get the former by passing in the latter. There are [plans](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Typeable) to improve this.

Comment: Notice that `Nothing :: Maybe x` already, so the `Nothing` value is *already* compatible with the type `Maybe Int`. This may or may not help you, depending on what you're after...